# Auto-incrementing a generic list using LINQ in C#

Tags: c#, linq, asp.net-mvc-3, linq-to-sql

Is there a good way to provide an "auto-increment" style index column (from 1..x) when projecting items using LINQ?

As a basic example, I'm looking for the index column below to go from 1 to the number of items in list.

```
var items = from s1 in list
    select new BrowsingSessionItemModel { Id = s1.Id, Index = 0 };
```

Iterating through the list would be the easy option but I was wondering if there was a better way to do this?

Comment: In general, you can generate a new incrementing enumerable using the Enumerable.Range(1, numOfItems), but in your case, using the Select overload is the better option for your needs.

Answer (score 15, accepted):

You can't do this with LINQ expressions. You could use the following [`.Select`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb534869.aspx) extension method though:

```
var items = list.Select((x, index) => new BrowsingSessionItemModel { 
    Id = x.Id, 
    Index = index 
});
```

Comment: What would be the most efficient way to start from 1, rather than 0?

Comment: I should have tried that first! I thought there might have been a way to set the identity seed value. Thanks again Darin.

Answer (score 9):

You can use the [overload of `Select`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb534869.aspx) which takes the provides the index to the projection as well:

```
var items = list.Select((value, index) => new BrowsingSessionItemModel { 
                                                Id = value.Id,
                                                Index = index
                                          });
```

Note that there is no query expression support for this overload. If you're actually fetching the values from a database (it's not clear whether `list` is really a `List<T>`) you should probably make sure you have an appropriate ordering, as otherwise the results are somewhat arbitrary.